# Using Local Gem Source Without Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm working on a Gem which I have in a repo on my local machine.

I have a project that uses this Gem (which for the purposes of this question I will call 'Project X'. Currently, any time I make a change to the Gem, in order to make these changes available to Project X, I have to:

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Did something"
$ bundle exec rake install
```

How can I tell project X to use my local Gem source rather than the installed Gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out like this:

```
gem 'some_gem', :path => "path/to/dir_containing_gemspec"
```